# Does the Rust Actix Web support MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, rust, actix-web

I have a new Backend Learning by Rust Programming.
Starting from Web Framework.
Since I would like to use Rust Backend with MongoDB so I have the example code of Nickel.
Anyway, I also see that there is Actix Web Framework.

Does Actix Web support MongoDB like Nickel?

The following example provide the Nickel with MongoDB.

```
//main.rs — Nickel
#[macro_use] 
extern crate nickel;
extern crate rustc_serialize;

#[macro_use(bson, doc)]
extern crate bson;
extern crate mongodb;

// Nickel
use nickel::{Nickel, JsonBody, HttpRouter, MediaType};
use nickel::status::StatusCode::{self};

// MongoDB
use mongodb::{Bson, bson, doc};
use mongodb::{Client, ThreadedClient};
use mongodb::db::ThreadedDatabase;
use mongodb::error::Result as MongoResult;

// bson
use bson::{Bson, Document};
use bson::oid::ObjectId;

// serde
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct User {
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    email: String
}

fn main(){
    let mut server = Nickel::new();
    let mut router = Nickel::router();

    router.get("/users", middleware! { |_req, _res|
        let client = Client::connect("localhost", 27017)
            .ok().expect("Error establishing connection.");

        let coll = client.db("rusty").collection("users");

        let mut cursor = coll.find(None, None).unwrap();
        let mut data_result = "{\"data\":[".to_owned();

        for (i, result) in cursor.enumerate() {

            if let Ok(item) = result {
                if let Some(&Bson::String(ref firstname)) = item.get("firstname") {
                    let string_data = if i == 0 {
                        format!("{},", firstname)
                    } else {
                        format!("{},", firstname)
                    };
                data_result.push_str(&string_data);
            }
        }
    }
    data_result.push_str("]}");

    format!("{}", data_result)

    });

    router.post("/users/new", middleware! { |_req, _res|
        let user = _req.json_as::<User>().unwrap();
        let firstname = user.firstname.to_string();
        let lastname = user.lastname.to_string();
        let email = user.email.to_string();

        let client = Client::connect("localhost", 27017)
            .ok().expect("Error establishing connection.");

        let coll = client.db("rusty").collection("users");

        match coll.insert_one(doc! {
            "firstname" => firstname,
            "lastname" => lastname,
            "email" => email
        }, None) {
            Ok(_) => (StatusCode::Ok, "Item saved!"),
            Err(e) => return _res.send(format!("{}", e))
        }
    });
    router.delete("/users/:id", middleware! { |_req, _res|
        let client = Client::connect("localhost", 27017)
            .ok().expect("Failed to initialize standalone client.");

        let coll = client.db("rusty").collection("users");

        let object_id = _req.param("id").unwrap();
        let id = match ObjectId::with_string(object_id) {
            Ok(oid) => oid,
            Err(e) => return _res.send(format!("{}", e))
        };
        match coll.delete_one(doc! {"_id" => id}, None) {
            Ok(_) => (StatusCode::Ok, "Item deleted!"),
            Err(e) => return _res.send(format!("{}", e))
        }
    });
    server.utilize(router);
    server.listen("0.0.0.0:3000").unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short version is yes, it will, since your libraries return `Result`s, and that's basically independent of whatever framework you decide to use.

The long answer is yes, but with a word of caution. As the official mongoDB client (the one you are using) and pretty much every alternative out there have fully blocking operations (from the time you call `find()` to the time you get the `Result`, the main thread is blocked), this means that your entire event loop will potentially block during that interval.

There seems to be no community effort to improve the underlying mongo C library, or to shift all the operations to another thread and provide data access to and from that thread, so you're short of options right now, sadly.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is very useful for me.

Answer (score 3):

Mongodb on it's last version allow multithreads on its core. 
For that reason r2d2_mongodb has been deprecated in December 2019.
It should then be possible to use RwLock on the connection and pass it to actix.